# JTextField - keyTyped не возвращает всю строку

Tags: java, swing

У меня есть поле `JTextField`
на нем висит обработчик `KeyTyped`
и мне нужно считать текст с этого поля
но у меня такая проблема, что когда вызываю `getText()` я получаю строку без последнего введенного символа
то есть ввел первую букву getText вернул пустую строку
ввел вторую букву получил строку с буквой которую ввел в первый раз и так далее
почему так происходит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант который предполагается к использованию [`.getDocument().addDocumentListener()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)

```
JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
lbl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 22));
JTextField tf = new JTextField();
tf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 22));
tf.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        lbl.setText(tf.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        lbl.setText(tf.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        lbl.setText(tf.getText());
    }
});

JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setSize(new Dimension(200,100));
f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
f.add(lbl);
f.add(tf);
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setVisible(true);
```

Так же худо-бедно сработает и Ваш подход если слушать не `keyTyped` а `keyReleased`, при этом поведение будет немного не стандартное, проверьте сами:

```
JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
lbl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 22));
JTextField tf = new JTextField();
tf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 22));
tf.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        lbl.setText(tf.getText());
    }
});
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setSize(new Dimension(200,100));
f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
f.add(lbl);
f.add(tf);
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Спасибо. первый вариант очень помог